# jQuery serialize does not pick up a select tag in a nested div

Tags: jquery, serialization

So I have this form

```
<form>
    <div>
        <span class="form_t">I Want To Trade In  
            <span id="trade_target"></span> 
        </span>
        <span class="form_t">With</span>

        <div class="selecting">
            <select>
                <option>A Mac</option>
                <option>An Iphone</option>  
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table id="tradein_table">
        <tr>
            <td class="textside">My contact Info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="textside">Mobile Number</td>
            <td class="inputside"><input type="text" name="Mobile" id="t_mobile"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="textside">First Name</td>
            <td class="inputside"><input type="text" id="t_first" name="Fname"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td class="textside">Last Name</td>
            <td class="inputside"><input type="text" id="t_last" name="Lname"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>    
            <td class="textside">Email</td>
            <td class="inputside"><input type="text" id="t_email" name="Email"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td class="textside">Company</td>
            <td class="inputside"><input id="t_company" type="text" name="Company"/>
        </td>               </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="submit_div">
        <input class="submit_form" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>  
</form>
```

And when I run it through jQuery `serialize()` it picks up all the tags except the select tag in the div.
Any ideas how to get it as well ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`serialize` only "picks up" elements with `name` attribute.

```
<select name="foo">
    <option>A Mac</option>
    <option>An Iphone</option>  
</select>
```

Your's:

```
<select>
    <option>A Mac</option>
    <option>An Iphone</option>  
</select>
```

Won't work.

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)